# Sending data from Recycler View Adapter to BroadcastReciever

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, broadcastreceiver

I am attempted to send data to the broadcast reciever when clicking on a cell in my recycler view. so that it may start a timer and display a notification when the timer has finished with the correct data.

However when I send the data to the Broadcast Reciever I recieve the incorrect data when the notification fires.

Here is the code from my Adapter class which is sending the data to the Boradcast Reciever which is in the method `public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position)`

```
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int ONE_SECOND = 1000;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BroadcastReminder.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("name", timer.getTimer_name());
                    bundle.putString("img", timer.getTimer_img());
                    intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                    long timeAtStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long duration_s = ONE_SECOND * 10;

                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            timeAtStart + duration_s, pendingIntent);
                }
            });
```

This will then start the service and when the notification fires, the Broadcast Reciever will recieve the data from the intent bundle and show the notification. (However the wrong data is being recieved, which is always the same element in the item each time)

```
public class BroadcastReminder extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle");
        String timer_name = bundle.getString("name");
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "notifyLemubit")
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setContentTitle("Timer Finished")
                .setContentText("Your " + timer_name + " Tree is Ready!")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(200, builder.build());

    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the pending intent flag being `0`. When it should have been `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to update the value each time it runs.